# how to add value to every second node in the list

Tags: c++, function, linked-list, nodes

**I try to traverse a linked list of values, and add some given value to every other node in the list. It should always start adding to the first node in the list, and then add on to every other node from there.**

Error is the program not giving any output but it most likely something wrong with the function

Here is what I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Declare the Node structure to be used for the linked list.
// Each node should have an int for data, and
// a pointer to the next node.
struct Node {
   int data;
   Node *pNext;
};

// Displays the list number values
void display( Node *pTemp){
    while( pTemp != NULL) {
        cout << pTemp->data << "->";
        pTemp = pTemp->pNext;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

// Create a new node, put the userInput number in it, and APPEND
// it to the END of the list.
void append(Node* &pHead, int userInput) {
    Node *pTemp = new Node;
    pTemp->data = userInput;
    pTemp->pNext = NULL;

    Node *pLast = pHead;
    // Find the last node on the list
    while(pLast != NULL && pLast->pNext != NULL) {
        pLast = pLast->pNext;
    }

    if( pLast == NULL) {
        // Make this new node the first node on an otherwise empty list
        pHead = pTemp;
    }
    else {
        // Append this new node to the end of the existing list
        pLast->pNext = pTemp;
    }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
//       *** Do not change anything above this point. ***
//------------------------------------------------------------------------ 

// add valueToAdd to every second node in the list
void addEveryOther(Node* &pHead, int valueToAdd) {
    
    // while there is a node after pTemp->pNext
    while(pHead->pNext != NULL || pHead != NULL) {
        // add valueToAdd to pTemp->data
        pHead->data += valueToAdd;
        // move pTemp to the next node
        pHead = pHead->pNext->pNext;
    }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
//       *** Do not change anything below this point. ***
//------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main() {
   int userInput;
   Node *pHead = NULL;  // pointer to the head of the list
   int value;
   
   // Create the linked list
   cout << "Enter list numbers separated by space, followed by -1: ";
   cin >> userInput;

   // Keep looping and appending nodes on the list until 
   // end-of-input flag of -1 is given
   while(userInput != -1) {
        // Store this number on the list
        append(pHead, userInput);
        cin >> userInput;
    }

    cout << "Enter value to add on: ";
    cin >> value;
    addEveryOther(pHead, value);
    display(pHead);

    return 0;

}// end main()
```

Here is the input :

```
2 8 9 5 11 3 6 -1
Enter value to add on: 5
```

and expected output :

```
7->8->14->5->16->3->11
```

Comment: What did you find out when you used a debugger?

Comment: @eerorika Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
addEveryOther (pHead=@0x7fffffffebd0: 0x55555556b750, valueToAdd=5)
    at main.cpp:75
75              pHead = pHead->pNext->pNext;

Comment: `while (pHead->pNext != NULL || pHead != NULL)` is wrong. That expression should be `while (pHead && pHead->pNext)` (or equivalent).

Comment: @mighty_cheetah43 And what was the value of `pHead->pNext` right before segfault?

Answer (score 2):

You need to think about the order in which you do things! And the logic in your conditions.

In the condition `pHead->pNext != NULL || pHead != NULL` you will dereference `pHead` *before* you check if it's a null pointer.

You need to do the checks in the opposite order, and use logical AND instead: `pHead != NULL && pHead->pNext != NULL`.